# why does this not work?? jquery ajax replace content in specific div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, dynamic

Below I have the code on my site, yet when I *click* on a *link* in this particular `div` it just opens a new window, why is this??

```
$(function(){   
//bind a click event to the nav links
$("#links a").bind("click", function(e){ 

    //keep the links from going to another page by preventing their default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //this = link; grab the url
    var pageLocation = this.href;

    //fire off an ajax request
    $.ajax({ 
        url: pageLocation, 

        //on success, set the html to the responsetext
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#biocontent").html(data.responseText); 
        } 
    });
});
});
```

EDIT:

I still havnt figured this out but here is where I am, my script is as follows

```
  <script type="text/javascript">(function(){   
//bind a click event to the nav links
$("#links a").bind("click", function(e){ 

    //keep the links from going to another page by preventing their default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //this = link; grab the url
    var pageLocation = $(this).attr("href")

    //fire off an ajax request
   $.ajax({ 
    url: pageLocation, 

    //on success, set the html to the responsetext
    success: function(data){ 
        $("#biocontent").html(data); 
    },
    dataType : "html"
     });
});
```

});

and here is how I am using it in my html`<div id="links">
            <a href="testvid.html"><img src="img/thumbs/img3.jpg" /></a>`

but still no go, please let me know what you think.

**EDIT**

So I took the minimal parts of this code and moved it into a new doc, and now it doesnt work at all, but i feel like I was having an issue with the Jquery, so now it is work and I am getting this error in the

> 17XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/semaj4712/Desktop/WME%20Website/testvid.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Which I have no idea what that means, so once I get it working here then I have to tackle the issue with the Jquery on the actual site.

Comment: Your success handler should just have the 'data' as the HTML (unless this is calling and getting a JSON or XML object, the signature for the handler is success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) where data is the body of the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call ajax with specified type that you want to get.

```
 $.ajax({ 
        url: pageLocation, 

        //on success, set the html to the responsetext
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#biocontent").html(data); 
        },
        dataType : "html"
    });
```

Comment: Your right but it still doesnt seem to work, could there be an issue because of where in my document the script is?

Comment: Error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is caused by you trying to access other domain. Response from that other domain should contain header param "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with your domain name or *

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the jQuery `load` function instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#links a").bind("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var pageLocation = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#biocontent").load(pageLocation,function(){
            alert('Loaded!');
        }); 
    });
});
```

It's the simplest and most efficient way to retrieve data and based on your code i'll assume thats only HTML.

Also, in your latest edit you are missing a semicolon when you define pageLocation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ill assume that with your code it should alert loaded if it were to work, and since it is not, I am not sure where my issue lies

Comment: Are you by any chance using a separate js file in which you put this code? Or is it on the same page as the HTML?

Comment: This code is the same page, i like to the Jquery in the header '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
'

Comment: If the href of the link is 'testvid.html', are you positive that that file is in the same folder as the file that contains the above script?

Comment: Yes it opens it, just not in the div

Answer (score 0):

In the success callback, your data object needs to be a **JSON** object in order to contain `responseText` so you would need to set the `dataType` field in the ajax call to `'json'`. In your current situation, it looks like you are retrieving *html* back. Check out the ajax documentation on [jquery.com](http://jquery.com) for more info.

Try using the `javascript console` in *chrome* or `firebug` in *firefox* to see any errors.  Your likely to find one on the page load

**Edit:**
You are working on your file system! You can't make ajax calls across your file system due to same origin policy enforced by browsers.  This means you can't make ajax requests to other servers. You would need to put your html pages on the same domain in order to complete the request.  WHat you are doing is like requesting data from www.google.com, when your domain is www.mydomain.com. You can only request data from www.mydomain.com.  The best thing for you to do would be to set up an apache server on your machine.

Comment: `this.href` should work if it is an `ANCHOR` with an `href` value: http://jsfiddle.net/nbMn6/

Comment: I made the change '$(this).attr("href");' instead of just 'this.href;' however I am a littler confused on the ajax call, if you could help me out a little bit there that would help.

Comment: Also I noticed an error at the beginning of the function where I had a $, is that what you are referring to on page load?

Comment: See my edit. Your problem is same origin policy. You can only make ajax requests to other pages in the same domain scope as the request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updates have you tried $("#biocontent").load(pageLocation)? It seems to be in line with what you are trying to do.

```
$(function(){   
    //bind a click event to the nav links
    $("#links a").bind("click", function(e){ 
        //keep the links from going to another page by preventing their default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //this = link; grab the url
        var pageLocation = this.href;
        $("#biocontent").load(pageLocation);

    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out, it had to do with using chrome and accessing files on my c drive, when using safari it worked, now I just have an issue with conflicting jquery but I will do some research on that now, thanks for all the help guys.