# How to properly do Ajax and handle form errors for a partial in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a newsletter signup box in the sidebar like this:

```
--------------------------------
|                   |          |
|                   |          |
|                   |__________|
|                   |NEWSLETTER|
|                   |          |
|                   |          |
--------------------------------
```

I've created a newsletter_controller with the following action:

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])
  end
end
```

I'm confused about a few things in rails:

**1. How to write the form with rails helpers that will post to this as an AJAX request?**

**2. If what the user enters is not a valid email or blank, how do I write out a message right there in the newsletter sidebar right next to the form field?**

**3. If the insert was successful, how do I replace the form with a "You're signed up" message.**

I'm new to both rails and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

1) You will need to read the rails and jquery APIs concerning handling forms and doing ajax posts. The former can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
The latter can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ . There are good examples for those on both of those pages

2) You will want to run some kind of basic regex on the input via javascript (and again when the data is posted from rails) to validate user input. Here is another stack overflow post concerning this: [jQuery Email Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112329/jquery-email-regex) . Here is an example of using it:

```
var fakeEmailAddress = "a@b.com";
var emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
var isAnEmailAddress = fakeEmailAddress.match(emailRegex);
if (!isAnEmailAddress) {
    alert("Yo bro. What's up with that email addy? Try again");
}
```

3) In the jquery ajax post, you can set the "success" function to do this. Check the link in #1. You will probably want to give the form an ID attribute and replace the form with the html data you retrieve from that post like in the following stackoverflow question: [why does this not work?? jquery ajax replace content in specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897564/why-does-this-not-work-jquery-ajax-replace-content-in-specific-div)